# How can I catch specific exceptions?

Tags: c#

Using Java, I liked to have specific exceptions classes on the catch clause, like this.

```
catch (FileNotFoundException | SQLException e)
```

Now, I'd like to have the same type of catch clause in C#.
is there a way to configure it so it has a similar behavior?

Comment: thats not a specific feature to rider - thats part of java. c# doesn't have the same.

Comment: Indeed, this isn't an IDE C# feature but a language feature. The closest you can get is `catch (Exception e) when (e is FileNotFoundException || e is SQLException)`. Or, in C# 9.0, `catch (Exception e) when (e is FileNotFoundException or SQLException)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned this isn't an IDE specific feature but more of a language feature.  Within your catch statement you can identify specific exceptions to catch such as:

```
catch (InvalidCastException e)
{
}
```

or you can get more in-depth with [exception filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

```
catch (ArgumentException e) when (e.ParamName == "…")
{
}
```

**Rider Solution**

If you are wanting rider to look for specific exceptions regardless this can be done through the Debug window.  Simply open your debug window then click View breakpoints and exceptions...[image: View breakpoints and exceptions...].

Next you will click the plus sign at the top of the new window and choose CLR Exception Breakpoints [image: CLR Exception Breakpoints]

On the new window you can choose which exceptions you want the debugger to be on the lookout for.

[image: Exception selection]

Comment: Is there a way to make Rider autocomplete with specific exceptions? When it autocompletes, it just puts a general exception clause. i'd ike it to put all specific exceptions instead.

Comment: Currently there is no way for it to autocomplete all possible exceptions that may be thrown.   It will however autocomplete (for example) ArgumentNullException if you start typing that.